# How to find what icon file nautilus is choosing to display?

Tags: nautilus, icons, mime-type, gvfs

I'm trying to set an icon association for a mime-type, but Nautilus is displaying a blank icon. How can I find which icon file Nautilus is choosing to display (the **path** to this blank icon)?

[image: Image with blank icon]

Relevant `gio info mcc.nex` output:

```
display name: mcc.nex
edit name: mcc.nex
name: mcc.nex
type: regular
size:  217017
attributes:
  standard::type: 1
  standard::is-hidden: FALSE
  standard::is-backup: FALSE
  standard::is-symlink: FALSE
  standard::name: mcc.nex
  standard::display-name: mcc.nex
  standard::edit-name: mcc.nex
  standard::copy-name: mcc.nex
  standard::icon: application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex, application-x-generic, application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex-symbolic, application-x-generic-symbolic
  standard::content-type: application/vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex
  standard::fast-content-type: application/vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex
  standard::size: 217017
  standard::allocated-size: 217088
  standard::symbolic-icon: application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex-symbolic, application-x-generic-symbolic, application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex, application-x-generic
```

Relevant `ls .local/share/icons/hicolor/*/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex*` output (none of these are a blank image):

```
.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex.png
.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex.png
.local/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex.png
.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex.png
.local/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex.png
.local/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes/application-vnd.treeviewer.nexus.nex.png
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I copied the icon (a `.png` file; but a `.svg` file will be better) into the directory `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/mimetypes/`, where `Adwaita` is my current icon scheme, and ran:

```
$ sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/
```

I am assuming that you have created or checked the correctness of your MIME type as explained in [Add a custom MIME type for individual users (GNOME Help web site)](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom-user.html.en).

***Note***: I tried to replicate the `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/` directory into my current user's `~/.local/share/icons/` directory and try the same, but it didn't work. :( Any comments, about user-based configuration, instead of system-wide configuration are welcome.

Comment: Thanks, AFAIK everything is correct with the mimetype configuration (as well as app association), especially since `gio` is able to report the correct mimetype. My problem is how I cannot debug which file Nautilus is choosing to display here.